# Merge PDFs from different subfolders with the same name

Tags: python, pdf

In `MAIN` folder, there are about 8 subfolders and each subfolder has PDF files. In those subfolders there are PDFs with the same name.
Example in Folder `1`, there is a pdf with the name `SamplePDF.pdf` and in folder `5`, there is a nother pdf with the same name `SamplePDF.pdf`. How can I merge these two similar pdfs in the name in one pdf file with the same name `SamplePDF.pdf` but in `OUTPUT` folder.

As for the PDFs that are unique to be copied only to the OUTPUT folder
This is my try so far

```
from pathlib import Path
import os

def list_files(dir):
    r = []
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dir):
        for name in files:
            r.append(os.path.join(root, name))
    return r

BASE_DIR = Path.cwd()
MAIN_DIR = BASE_DIR / 'MAIN'
OUTPUT_DIR = BASE_DIR / 'OUTPUT'

try:
    shutil.rmtree(OUTPUT_DIR)
except:
    pass
OUTPUT_DIR.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)

mylist = list_files(MAIN_DIR)
print(mylist)
```

I have an idea of code that merge pdf files stored in python list. But how can I create lists of all the files with the same name?

Looping through the list

```
for f in mylist:
    print(f)
```

I got this as output:

```
C:\Users\Future\Desktop\MAIN\1\1.pdf
C:\Users\Future\Desktop\MAIN\1\2.pdf
C:\Users\Future\Desktop\MAIN\1\3.pdf
C:\Users\Future\Desktop\MAIN\1\4.pdf
C:\Users\Future\Desktop\MAIN\1\5.pdf
C:\Users\Future\Desktop\MAIN\1\6.pdf
C:\Users\Future\Desktop\MAIN\2\1.pdf
C:\Users\Future\Desktop\MAIN\2\2.pdf
C:\Users\Future\Desktop\MAIN\2\3.pdf
C:\Users\Future\Desktop\MAIN\2\4.pdf
C:\Users\Future\Desktop\MAIN\2\5.pdf
C:\Users\Future\Desktop\MAIN\2\6.pdf
C:\Users\Future\Desktop\MAIN\3\1.pdf
C:\Users\Future\Desktop\MAIN\3\2.pdf
C:\Users\Future\Desktop\MAIN\3\3.pdf
C:\Users\Future\Desktop\MAIN\3\4.pdf
C:\Users\Future\Desktop\MAIN\3\5.pdf
C:\Users\Future\Desktop\MAIN\3\6.pdf
C:\Users\Future\Desktop\MAIN\4\1.pdf
C:\Users\Future\Desktop\MAIN\4\2.pdf
C:\Users\Future\Desktop\MAIN\4\3.pdf
C:\Users\Future\Desktop\MAIN\4\4.pdf
C:\Users\Future\Desktop\MAIN\4\5.pdf
C:\Users\Future\Desktop\MAIN\4\6.pdf
C:\Users\Future\Desktop\MAIN\5\1.pdf
C:\Users\Future\Desktop\MAIN\5\2.pdf
C:\Users\Future\Desktop\MAIN\5\3.pdf
C:\Users\Future\Desktop\MAIN\5\4.pdf
C:\Users\Future\Desktop\MAIN\5\5.pdf
C:\Users\Future\Desktop\MAIN\5\6.pdf
C:\Users\Future\Desktop\MAIN\6\1.pdf
C:\Users\Future\Desktop\MAIN\6\2.pdf
C:\Users\Future\Desktop\MAIN\6\3.pdf
C:\Users\Future\Desktop\MAIN\6\4.pdf
C:\Users\Future\Desktop\MAIN\6\5.pdf
C:\Users\Future\Desktop\MAIN\6\6.pdf
C:\Users\Future\Desktop\MAIN\7\1.pdf
C:\Users\Future\Desktop\MAIN\7\2.pdf
C:\Users\Future\Desktop\MAIN\7\3.pdf
C:\Users\Future\Desktop\MAIN\7\4.pdf
C:\Users\Future\Desktop\MAIN\7\5.pdf
C:\Users\Future\Desktop\MAIN\7\6.pdf
C:\Users\Future\Desktop\MAIN\8\1.pdf
C:\Users\Future\Desktop\MAIN\8\2.pdf
C:\Users\Future\Desktop\MAIN\8\3.pdf
C:\Users\Future\Desktop\MAIN\8\4.pdf
C:\Users\Future\Desktop\MAIN\8\5.pdf
C:\Users\Future\Desktop\MAIN\8\6.pdf
```

I need an idea of how to create python lists of each item that has the same name in pdf name?

Answer (score 1):

1- create a function to detect duplicates:

```
def duplicates(files):
    store=[]
    checked=[]
    for i in range(len(files)):
        counter =1 
        for j in range(i+1,len(files)):
            if files[i] not in checked and files[j]==files[i] :
                counter +=1 
        if counter > 1 :
            store.append(files[i])
            checked.append(files[i])
    return store
```

2- refer mylist to it:

```
mylist = list_files(MAIN_DIR)
duplicated = duplicates(mylist)
print(mylist,duplicated)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. As for the duplicated list is empty as for my side.

Comment: I noticed two python lists as output. The first python list in output is so close to what I need. I just need this list to be of sub-lists. I mean each group would be in a separate python list inside the main list.

Comment: you may separate the last part of the address and save them into a new list then find the duplicateds

Comment: I reviewed the output and found that the duplicated list is empty, I just got the files list. My target is to make sub-lists of the main list. The sub-list will have the similar pdf names from any subfolder. Sometimes the file is unique in all the subfolders, in that case to be in separate sub-list. Example, say I have a pdf with the name `STACK.pdf` and this file only exists in one sub folder, so this will be in sub-lst alone `['C:\Users\Future\Desktop\MAIN\3\3.pdf']`